# php SimpleXML exits with Killed

Tags: php, simplexml

I am trying to parse 16MB XML File with SimpleXML, but the only one Input I receive is "Killed".

I am using also the LIBXML_PARSEHUGE param.

```
$xml = new \SimpleXMLElement($content, LIBXML_PARSEHUGE);
```

Some idea, where I can look for Error or someone knows the error?

Comment: What version of PHP and libxml do you have (as output by `phpinfo()` / `php -i`)

Comment: I have analysed the problem and I saw, that not the SimpleXML is the problem, but the CURL. Very strange. When I got the content over file_get_contents() it has worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem. Turns out the error message `Killed` comes from the kernel and not from PHP itself. Have a look inside `/var/log/kern.log`

In my case my VirtualBox VM was running another memory intense operation in parallel and ran out of memory and the kernel decided to kill the PHP operation.